# can't access phpmysql using url but can from domain

Tags: apache

I have a site running on an AWS EC2 instance and have loaded an app using virtual env and all is well.  I can access the app using my domain name (http://mydomain.name/directory/).  This site does not utilize a database. All is well.

I am trying to install another app that doesn't not require a virtualenv but does require a mysql/phpmyadmin.  So I've installed mysql and phpmyadmin.

I can access the database in terminal mode - ssh into server.

NOW, Strange thing is I can access phpmyadmin when I use the domain (23.23.234.234/phpmyadmin)

But I can not access it using the name (http://mydomain.name/phpmyadmin)

I know the DNS is working because I can access the site using the domain name for the previous app I installed.

For the life of me I can not figure this out?  Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't it be `http://mydomain.name/phpmyadmin` ?  Instead of `http://mydomain.name.phpmyadmin`, Also, ensure you have the proper capitalization.

Comment: yes yes.  I just typed it incorrectly in the description above.  I edited it and now it reads correctly.

Comment: ok mod_rewrite was not enabled and .htaccess was not configured.  All Set now.